# How do I pause a Bootstrap progress bar width transition using Angular?

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently using a Bootstrap progress bar with a css transition to run the width from 0 to 100%, at the same time as a $timeout is running. When I open a confirm() box, the $timeout pauses, but the css transition doesn't. Is there a better way of linking the two together so the transition can be paused as well?

Here is my code - it listens for a start attribute to change to true.

```
.directive('myTimer', function($timeout){
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            duration: '@',
            start: '@'
        },
        replace: true,
        template: "<div class='progress'><div class='progress-bar' role='progressbar' style='-webkit-transition: width {{duration}}s linear; transition: width {{duration}}s linear'></div></div>",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            attrs.$observe('start', function(a){
                if (a === 'true') {
                    $timeout(function(){
                        element.addClass('active');
                    }, 1);
                }
            });
        }
    };
})

.controller('myController', function($scope){
    var chosenTimeSec = $scope.chosenTime * 1000;
    $scope.timer = $timeout(function(){
        $scope.finish();
    }, chosenTimeSec);
})

----

<my-timer duration="{{chosenTime}}" start="{{timerStarted}}"></my-timer>
```

Comment: Depends on the code that you have.

Comment: Please provide the code you're working with to try and make this happen, along with a mockup on Bootply or JS Fiddle if possible.

Comment: Code added just now.

Comment: You'll need to break the transition into segments using `aria-valuenow` and `width` and only run the subsequent segments if no confirm is triggered.